# Unable to connect to test.mosquito.org using Paho android client

Tags: android

I am following some examples made by the Paho developers to learn how to apply the Paho Android Client library (https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android) since I am new to it. I have followed all the steps but after testing the app with `tcp://test.mosqitto.org:1883`, its keeps giving me unable to connect to server errors, even though everything works fine.

Below are portion codes from https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android.

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.DisconnectedBufferOptions;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttMessageListener;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallbackExtended;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
    import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PahoExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private HistoryAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;

final String serverUri = "tcp://test.mosqitto.org:1883";

final String clientId = "";
final String subscriptionTopic = "dannies";
final String publishTopic = "dannies";
final String publishMessage = "Hello World!";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            publishMessage();
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.history_recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(new ArrayList<String>());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), serverUri, clientId);
    mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
        @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {

            if (reconnect) {
                addToHistory("Reconnected to : " + serverURI);
                // Because Clean Session is true, we need to re-subscribe
                subscribeToTopic();
            } else {
                addToHistory("Connected to: " + serverURI);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
            addToHistory("The Connection was lost.");
        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            addToHistory("Incoming message: " + new String(message.getPayload()));
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

        }
    });

    MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mqttConnectOptions.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(false);

    try {
        //addToHistory("Connecting to " + serverUri);
        mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                DisconnectedBufferOptions disconnectedBufferOptions = new DisconnectedBufferOptions();
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferEnabled(true);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setBufferSize(100);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setPersistBuffer(false);
                disconnectedBufferOptions.setDeleteOldestMessages(false);
               // mqttAndroidClient.setBufferOpts(disconnectedBufferOptions);
                subscribeToTopic();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                addToHistory("Failed to connect to: " + serverUri);
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void addToHistory(String mainText){
    System.out.println("LOG: " + mainText);
    mAdapter.add(mainText);
    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), mainText, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void subscribeToTopic(){
    try {
        mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(subscriptionTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                addToHistory("Subscribed!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                addToHistory("Failed to subscribe");
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException ex){
        System.err.println("Exception whilst subscribing");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void publishMessage(){

    try {
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
        message.setPayload(publishMessage.getBytes());
        mqttAndroidClient.publish(publishTopic, message);
        addToHistory("Message Published");
        if(!mqttAndroidClient.isConnected()){
            addToHistory(" messages in buffer.");
        }
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        System.err.println("Error Publishing: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Please is there something I am doing wrong.